# PIP MVC - PHP Controllers

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Hi I'm pretty new to MVC framework. I decided to build a small application in MVC to get better understanding.

I googled around and found **PIP** framework that i can use for simple application and then modify once i will get complete understanding.

PIP can be found [here](http://gilbitron.github.io/PIP/)

Now i have one question that by looking to PIP framework, do i need to design to new controller for every page that i will use.

For e.g

```
applications/
      views/ 
        home.php
        about.php
        contact.php
      controllers/
         main.php
         aboutus.php ??
         contactus.php ??
```

For eg. my default controller and view is `main.php` and `home.php` and i have a controller for main.php as below:

```
<?php
     class Main extends Controller {

     function index()
     {
        $template = $this->loadView('home');
        $template->set('title', "Welcome Homepage");
        $template->render();
      } 
  }
?>
```

So, in this way, do i need to create new `conrollers` for about and contact.php

Comment: Yes you need a controller for every request. However, most MVC frameworks have **routes**, where you can select default controllers, or specific routes that might let you select a "main" controller to handle different method pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pip the URL defines the controller and function that will be executed. If you want the contact page to be at `mysite.com/contact`, you do need to add a Contact controller.

You do not need to create a new controller for every page. Lets assume you had a forum. You could have the following urls:

- `mysite.com/blog/write`
- `mysite.com/blog/view/15`

These different URLs would all be handled in one controller, `blog.php`

```
<?php

class Blog extends Controller {

    public function write()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }

    public function view($postId)
    {
       echo 'Viewing post: ' . $postId;
    }
}
```

Comment: no, but here you are again emphasizing on one blog page which have write and view. but i am talking about multiple pages

Comment: Lets talk about pages as separate URLs. In my example you have 2 pages, `.com/blog/write/` and `.com/blog/view/13`. You can re-use the controller as long as you don't mind the first path being the same `.com/blog/<func>`. If you want to have different paths eg: `.com/path1` and `.com/path2` you'll need different controllers.

Comment: This helped me now when i was designing blog of the website.

Answer (score 3):

`PIP`'s routing is internalized and requires a specific scaffolding of your controllers:

When you go to:

```
example.com/main
```

It looks for the controller `main` and then the function `index` by default.

If you were going to have 1 controller per view, then it would be something like:

```
example.com/main
class Main extends Controller

example.com/about
class About extends Controller

example.com/contact
class Contact extends Controller
```

However, if you went with a default `page` controller, this would greatly simplify the scaffolding:

```
example.com/page/{about|contact|main}

class Page extends Controller {
    public function about (){

    }

    public function contact(){

    }

    public function main(){

    }
}
```

Now 1 controller will handle the delivery of each of these pages.

Comment: can't i modify to use routing file??

Comment: and with ur approach, `page` will always be visible in my URL nd that is something not nice.

Comment: @Gags While that's absolutely true, you can change the Routing structure yourself ( i don't know how PIP's works ) and point to to a specific action within a specific controller.

Comment: Okii.  But then how can i make sure that page does not appear even in routes.php. I am not aware if page will be visible or not in url if i am using routing.

Answer (score 0):

I also used PIP as a starter framework, and extended it to include some additional functionality.  I even started to document my efforts, but other projects have taken me in other directions.
Happy to share what I have, and some documentation on my PIP efforts can be found at http://www.shed22.com/pip.

Let me know if you would like a copy of the source code and a sample application.

Stephen